# Center formating with date in Python XlsxWriter Excel365

Tags: python, pandas, excel, date, xlsxwriter

I'm having trouble formatting a date cell while retrieving data from MS SQL and transferring it to Excel365 using Pandas in Python.
After entering the data into Excel, the date column did not adopt the "center" and "vcenter" formatting. I do not know why

```
import os.path

import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

conn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://user:user@localhost/db?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
table_name = "table_name"
photo_path = "D:/tmp/product_photos/"
file_data_path = "D:/tmp/pythonProject/Project1/data/"
plik = file_data_path + "File_"

engine = db.create_engine(conn_string)
connection = engine.connect()


def photo_extensions(path):
    files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))]
    ext_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        ext_dict[file_name] = file
    return ext_dict

with conn:
    df_raw = pd.read_sql("select top 10 * from table_name", connection)
    df_mag = df_raw["magazine"].unique().tolist()

sku_extension = photo_extensions(photo_path)

df_raw["images"] = photo_path + df_raw["sku"].map(sku_extension)
mag_list = df_raw["magazine"].unique()

if not df_raw.empty:
    for mag in mag_list:
        row = 2
        file_name = plik + mag + ".xlsx"
        df_for_mag = df_raw[df_raw["magazine"] == mag]
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine="xlsxwriter")
        df_for_mag.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
        cell_format = workbook.add_format()
        
        for image in df_for_mag["images"]:
            if pd.notna(image):
                data = BytesIO(open(image, "rb").read())
                row_insert = "K" + str(row)
                im = Image.open(image)
                width = im.size[0]
                height = im.size[1]
                worksheet.set_row_pixels(row-1, height)
                worksheet.set_column_pixels("K:K", width)
                worksheet.insert_image(row_insert, image, {"image_data": data})
            worksheet.write_blank(row-1, 10, None, cell_format)
            row += 1

        center_format = workbook.add_format({"align": "center", "valign": "vcenter"})
        worksheet.set_column("A:J", None, center_format)

        worksheet.autofit()
        name_format = workbook.add_format({"align": "left", "valign": "vcenter"})
        worksheet.set_column("C:C", 50, name_format)

        date_format = workbook.add_format({"align": "center", "valign": "vcenter"})
        worksheet.set_column("G:G", None, date_format)

        writer.save()
        print(file_name)
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsO6X.jpg)

I tried changing the formatting to `{'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'}`, but it's the same output.
I tried get date with string format from datebase, but then excel sees the text, not the date

Comment: The reason this happens is that Pandas applies a cell format when writing dates because it needs to apply a number format. The cell format then overrides the column format. You can change the Pandas date/time formats ([XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output)) but not the other properties. Probably the only way to do it is to overwrite the cell data with data from the dataframe and the required cell formats.